# jQuery HTML Content Slider with Semi-Static Background

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I am looking for a jQuery HTML Content slider plugin that mimics this functionality:
http://www.4templates.com/website-templates/277677692-WT00915/demo/#red

I like how the divs in the foreground slide, but also how the background slightly moves in the direction of the sliding content as well. I have tried to search for this plugin but can't find it! Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't so much a slider plugin but a bespoke website template, which is what it is exactly advertised as a 'website template'.

I would suggest looking at [this tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery) which puts together a basic version of what you have linked.

[Horizontal demo](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/horizontal.html)

Comment: No problem, glad it was of help.